# On a dual boot after some days it crash on booting

Tags: boot

I installed win-10 and ubuntu on a dual-boot (two drives, ssd for OS).

Some days it ran fine but suddenly it goes like screenshot shows. 
If I restart the pc it goes directly to the bios mode (no grub or anything).

It says:

```
/dev/sda5: clean, 198072/656... files, ...../..... blocks
[ 67.73... ] systemd-journalID[342]: failed to write entry (28 items ...) ignoring: read-only file system
```

[boot problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCCdh.jpg)

[boot problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8mr0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Disable [Fast Startup](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) in Windows and try again.

Also [check](https://www.google.com/search?q=bios%20fast%20boot&safe=active&sxsrf=ALeKk01o9NX247TWrqZxQ-CH189PiIqWKQ:1584490218856&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3jZSF3qLoAhVxx4sKHVXQBrIQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1366&bih=696) your BIOS for Fast Boot, Secure Boot. These should be disabled.

> Why disable fast startup?
>  Leaving fast startup enabled shouldn't
>   harm anything on your PC — it's a feature built into Windows — but
>   there are a few reasons why you might want to nevertheless disable it.
>
> One of the major reasons is if you're using Wake-on-LAN, which will
>   likely have problems when your PC is shut down with fast startup
>   enabled. Others would like to save the hard drive space that is
>   usually taken up with the hibernation file, and Linux users will
>   likely see complications with dual boot and virtualization.
>   Furthermore, some users have even reported that power buttons on their
>   keyboard will not work and fans in their PCs will continue spinning.
>   These problems are by no means across the board, but they can prove to
>   be frustrating. Finally, Windows 10 updates might not install properly
>   if you have fast startup enabled.

Comment: Yes I had done it when i installed the Ubuntu.  fast boot - disabled (bios and os) secure boot -disabled (deleted APK), disk formate- GPT, I have two dongle (wifi and bluetooth for keyboard & mouse), CSM mood enabled. When i installed it runs fine but after some day it happen..... again and again.... I dont know why ? if u need more info please ask me.

Comment: Some people were saying their Secure Boot have been reenabled by itself. Check now if it have not been enabled somehow by os.